# janus graph vertex multivalue becomes single value when control enter in reduce phase , can any one suggest on this?

Tags: apache-spark, gremlin, tinkerpop, tinkerpop3, janusgraph

we are using tinkerpop vertex program custom implemented and implemented map-reduce custom implementation , we have data in Janus graph with for example sample vertex with different properties, with one property having multi values like below .

foods : ["a","b"]

out vertex program retrieving the multi value , in the map function also am seeing vertex property has two values , but after map function , when it enter reduce function am seeing this property have single value only

foods : ["a"]

what might happen between reduce and map function , what changed multi values to single value ?

can any one please help us .

Comment: @stephen mallette any idea on this

Comment: What is your map function?